# No suitable driver found for jbdc:sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

He seguido todos los pasos que encuentro, he intentado con varias versiones del driver pero aún así no me deja conectar y dice que la versión del driver no es compatible
Este es el código que uso para intentar conectarme

```
package dbtienda;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.*;


public class DBtienda {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    String dbName = "tienda";
    String user = "conexion";
    String pass = "3312";
    try {
        //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jbdc.SQLServerDriver");
        //String connectionDB = "jbdc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;database=" 
        String connectionDB = "jbdc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-2V4ND64M\\SQLEXPRESS;database=" 
                //+ dbName + ";user = " + user + ";password = " + pass + ";";
                + dbName + ";integratedSecurity=true;";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionDB);            
    }

    /*catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }*/
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return connection;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(DBtienda.getConnection() != null)
        System.out.println("Conexión exitosa!");
}

}
```

Este es el error completo

Error: No suitable driver found for jbdc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-2V4ND64M\SQLEXPRESS;database=tienda;integratedSecurity=true;

Comment: jbdc:sqlserver => jdbc:sqlserver

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero ahora me sale otro error: Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verifique los nombres del servidor y de instancia, compruebe que no hay ningún firewall bloqueando el tráfico UDP al puerto 1434. Para SQL Server 2005 o posterior, verifique que el servicio SQL Server Browser se está ejecutando en el host

Mi firewall está desactivado y los nombres están bien

Comment: *... verifique que el servicio SQL Server Browser se está ejecutando en el host* ¿Has verificado que el servicio está iniciado?

Comment: Verifica que el puerto no este bloqueado y que el servidor de datos permita la conexión remota por el mismo puerto.

Answer (score 0):

Debes verificar:

- Si el servicio de MS SQL Server esta iniciado (En windows services.msc).
- Como entras al servidor? Usuario SA? o Credenciales de Windows? si es con credenciales de windows, va integratedSecurity=true y si no va user=sa; password=TU_PASSWORD en la URL de conexión.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo necesitas  el dirver de autoriazacion para el sql

“https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774”

Descarga y lo pones dentro de tu carpeta  de dependiendo la version que usas 64 o 32 bits